# reflection of a mirror surface

Tags: rendering, mirror

[image]I recently started studying 3d and I had such an artifact in cycles on the reflection of a mirror surface. Maybe someone knows how to fix it? Or how to improve the render settings?
[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=epnSXSZr" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/epnSXSZr/)  I'm attaching a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in Cycles render engine but you are in *Material* preview. In this preview mode Blender uses Eevee, not Cycles. Eevee is not very accurate regarding reflections, lights, etc. In your case to avoid this bad reflection effect you need to switch to Eevee and in the *Render panel > Screen Space Reflections* > right click on *Thickness* to *Reset to Default Value* (it's currently 12.7, the default value is 0.2):

[image]